# Reducer code for handling normalized state that gets out of sync

Tags: redux

Suppose I have a normalized piece of state that looks like this, say for a todo list:

```
{
  ids: [1,2,3,4],
  dataEntities: {
     1: { //the todo item name, content, due date, etc},
     2: { //same }
     //etc..
  },
  metadataEntities: {
     1: { //info about when the todo was last edited, saved to server, etc }
     // etc..
  }
}
```

And, of course, I've written my reducers so that any time I add or delete something from `ids` I also update the corresponding entries in `dataEntities` and `metadataEntities`.  Accordingly, my state *should* always be consistent in the sense that if something exists in `ids` it will have entries in each of the entities.  As a result, a reducer that depends on this consistency *should* work fine.

For example, a reducer action like this should be OK (assume i'm using RTK or Immer so it's OK to write an apparently state-mutating reducer):

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    //...
    "editTodo":
      const id = action.payload.id
      const newTodoContent = action.payload.content
      if(state.ids.includes(id)) {
        state.dataEntities[id].content = newTodoContent
        state.metaDataEntities[id].lastEdit = new Date().toString()
      } else return
   }
}
```

In other words, the statements inside the `if` block should be fine.  If an id exists in `ids`, it should have corresponding entities in state.dataEntities and state.metaDataEntities. And, indeed, if the initializers and reducers that setup and maintain those entities are properly written, that will always be the case.

But... what if they are not?  A piece of a sloppy code, a strange edge case, etc.--for some reason things have gotten 'out of sync' in the sense that an id in `ids` doesn't have a corresponding entity in one of the entity arrays.  What's the "right" way in redux for a reducer to handle that?

In other words, how should I fill in the missing code here:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    //...
    "editTodo":
      const id = action.payload.id
      const newTodoContent = action.payload.content
      if(state.ids.includes(id)) {
        if(state.dataEntities[id] === undefined || state.metadataEntities[id] === undefined
        {
          //WHAT GOES HERE?
        }
        state.dataEntities[id].content = newTodoContent
        state.metaDataEntities[id].lastEdit = new Date().toString()
      } else return
   }
}
```

A few options I've considered:

1. Return unaltered state.  That seems fine from a purely redux
   perspective but not very helpfully to me in terms of spotting why my
   app isn't working.  (Why isn't a todo updating?)
2. Throw.  That's a no-no because this is a reducer, which needs to be a pure function.
3. Do some logging or error notification outside of the reducer, for example in middleware.  OK, but that's not really answering the
   question--I'm trying to figure out how to write safe *reducer*
   code that handles the fact that there might be a problem in code
   outside the reducer (including middleware).
4. State variable that holds errors.  This is the best I've come up with so far, namely, have a variable or object in state that a
   reducer can log to if it runs into inconsistent state.  So, the
   "WHAT GOES HERE" line would look like `state.stateError = "Inconsistent entity state"` (or something more specific, ideally).

Is there a recommended or best-practice solution(s) for this type of situation?

Much appreciated.

Comment: As a first observation, note that [Redux Toolkit's `createEntityAdapter` API](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter) will do much of that normalization updating work for you.

Comment: @markerikson, absolutely.  I've actually been having trouble understanding how RTK handles this type of situation, i.e., a situation where a reducer could be asked to update an id with no corresponding entity.  It looks to me from the source (and I may be reading it wrong) like if it's asked to update an id that doesn't have a corresponding entity, it just doesn't do it rather than indicating an error.  And maybe that's absolutely the right way to do it, but that's part of what led to this question.  (Also, can't let this comment go without thanks for all your work on RTK!)

Comment: Yeah, reducers are supposed to determine what state updates happen in response to any given action, and "no update for this action" is an entirely valid result even if it's an action the reducer _does_ care about.  That also goes along with the suggest approach of modeling actions as "events".  But, it's still up to you to decide if that's the semantics you want _your_ reducers to have.  (Oh, and: thank you, and you're welcome! :)  )